# Приём UDP пакетов за NAT'ом

Tags: python, сеть, nat

## Теория

Я получаю доступ в интернет через роутер, то есть, в отличии от роутера, не имею внешнего IP.
Так же имеется сервер, но уже с внешним IP.

Верно ли, что отправленный мной UDP пакет, проходя через роутер, претерпит преобразование исходящих адреса и порта, и пробросит новый порт наружу чтобы сервер смог прислать мне ответ?
То есть если я отправляю пакет с порта 5000, то, достигнув роутера, номер исходящего порта поменяется на случайное `x` и роутер запомнит, что все входящие пакеты на порт `x` нужно перебрасывать на мой IP к 5000'ому порту.

## Практика

Если это верно, то почему не подтверждается следующим кодом?

Пакет отправляю так

```
import socket
import sys

UDP_IP = #IP сервера
UDP_PORT = #порт, который слушает сервер
MESSAGE = "Hi!"

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, # Internet
                     socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
sock.bind(('0.0.0.0', 5000))
sock.sendto(MESSAGE, (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
```

Сразу после отправки начинаю слушать

```
import socket
import sys

UDP_IP = #мой внутренний IP
UDP_PORT = 5000

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, # Internet
                     socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))

while True:
    data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024) # buffer size is 1024 bytes
    print "received message:", data
```

Но прослушка ничего не выводит. Почему?

Всё тоже самое, но в рамках локальной сети, работает корректно.

Comment: Как настроен маршрутизатор -- это не сюда, а к его администратору. Тем более, что маршрутизаторы -- они разные бывают сами по себе, а уж как они сконфигурированы... А пакеты есть или нет? Ну запустите сниффер (tcpdump, wireshark и т.п.) и посмотрите, прилетает ли ответ, и если да, то на какой порт.

Comment: @alexz неужели такая основополагающая функция может быть отключена или вольно сконфигурирована? Я так понимаю, её используют торренты и skype, которые, например, успешно функционируют на локальной машине.

Сниффером посмотрю, спасибо.

Comment: @jofsey А как же защищать офисных юзеров от атак недремлющего врага (ботнетов вроде меньше не становится?).

Answer (score 3):

> Верно ли, что отправленный мной UDP
> пакет, проходя через роутер, претерпит
> преобразование исходящих адреса и
> порта, и пробросит новый порт наружу
> чтобы сервер смог прислать мне ответ?
> То есть если я отправляю пакет с порта
> 5000, то, достигнув роутера, номер
> исходящего порта поменяется на
> случайное x и роутер запомнит, что все
> входящие пакеты на порт x нужно
> перебрасывать на мой IP к 5000'ому
> порту.

Чаще всего - да.

```
UDP_PORT = #порт, который слушает сервер
```

Вам, вероятно, нужен не порт, который слушается сервером, а внешний порт, на который роутер отобразил внутренний порт, на котором вы реально слушаете. Иначе говоря, вам нужно:

1. Послать пакет на машину с известным IP (назову сервером). Роутер пробросит порты. Сервер должен запомнить, с какого порта ему пришел пакет.
2. Ответить клиенту на этот порт, который он запомнил на предыдущем шаге.

Кстати, можете почитать: [Peer-to-Peer Communication Across Network Address Translators](http://www.brynosaurus.com/pub/net/p2pnat/). Когда-то я реализовывал описанную там методику (аналогичная вашей теории) и все более-менее работало.

Comment: Тут я немного не точно описал. Оба приведённых скрипта выполняются на локальной машине. На серверной же происходит ровно то, что вы описали: получаю входящий пакет с уже проброшенного порта и отправляю ответ ровно туда же.
Если вы имели в виду это, то, увы, не работает. Если другое, то я не понимаю почему `UDP_PORT`, на который отправляется пакет с локально ймашины на сервер, нельзя инициализировать портом, который слушает сервер, учитывая, что у сервера внешний IP и ни за какими NAT'ами он не прячется.

Comment: @Jofsey, чтобы не было недопониманий, дайте взглянуть тогда на полный код. )

Answer (score 1):

По умолчанию, роутеры не умеют перебрасывать udp пакеты. Им нужно прописать как именно это делать. Это можно сделать как через интерфейс роутера, так и программно. Этим пользуются скайп и торренты. Называется эта функциональность - *UPNP*. Начните гуглить по словам "UPNP Router Port Mapping Tool" и найдете все что нужно. Например [эту](http://www.sharewareconnection.com/software.php?list=Upnp+Router+Port+Mapping+Tool) подборку готовых программ. А дальше осталось разобраться, как ими пользоваться.

По факту, все эти программы просто связывают два порта на роутере (один в внутреннюю сеть, другой - во внешнюю).

Не удивлюсь, если в питоновских либах будет готовая библиотека.

Не все роутеры это умеют.

Comment: Не вводите человека в заблуждение. Для UDP hole punching никакого UPnP port mapping'а и прочего port forwarding'а не нужно.

Скайп и торренты пользуются UPnP port mapping если он есть. Если нет — пробивают дыру в NAT'е каким-нибудь STUN'ом. Если, конечно, реализация NAT позволяет пробить дыру.

Comment: Обработка TCP и UDP на NAT принципиально не отличается. Другое дело, что могут существовать настройки не пропускать UDP, не запоминать UDP-сокеты, быстро забывать UDP-сокеты, и т.п.