# Организация UDP через интернет

Tags: vps, udp, 3g

Добрый день.
Ситуация такая: есть VPS, работающий в локальной сети и имеющий внешний статический IP. На VPS запущено серверное ПО, которое обменивается UDP-пакетами с клиентами. В локальной сети все работает нормально.
1) Возможно ли организовать обмен UDP-пакетами с клиентами из внешней сети (например, со смартфонами, подключенными к 3G, у которых IP динамический). Проброс портов из локалки во внешку не помогает, т.к. у клиентов нет статического внешнего IP.
2) Как организовать проверку доступности сервера (если это вообще возможно для UPD)?

Answer (score 1):

1) Внешние клиенты чаще всего [в состоянии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/167582/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%91%D0%BC-udp-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B7%D0%B0-nat%D0%BE%D0%BC) достучаться до сервера через NAT. Это мало отличается от того же TCP.

2) Проверка доступности сервера клиентом осуществляется крайне просто - отвечает - значит, доступен.

3) Учтите, что UDP не гарантирует, что отправленные пакеты дойдут, и при этом дойдут в правильном порядке. Есть подозрение, что вы изобретаете TCP.

Comment: 1) Да, из внешки в локалку нет проблема. А если нужно наоборот, передавать пакет из локалки во внешку? Как NAT узнает, куда его отправлять: